# In BigQuery, can we set a column's description metadata from a subquery or function instead of statically?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, metadata

I'm aware we can set column descriptions by defining the value statically when creating the table, i.e.

```
Create Table table_name (
    member_id int64 options(description = "Unique system-generated ID for a member")
    ...
);
```

But is it possible to set the descriptions dynamically instead? I would like to do something like this-

```
Create table table_name (
    member_id int64 options(description = (Select "some query" From some_table))
);
```

Which then opens me up to a whole host of options, specifically setting the description dynamically based on what another table's column description is using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS, rather than having to set each column's description by hand for each table. However, I get an error message `Expected constant expression but found unsupported statement or clause; failed to evaluate 'description' in OPTIONS` when running the above.

Another thing I tried is creating and calling a function, i.e.

```
Create Temp Function get_description(string col_name) AS (
    (Select "some query"
     From some_table
     Where column = col_name)
);

Create table table_name (
    member_id int64 options(description = (get_description("member_id")))
);
```

But that throws a similar error message.

If both are not possible, I can still utilize a function and simply declare and set variables for each column. But some of my tables will have upwards of 40 columns, so if I can avoid having to declare and set a variable for each column description, that would be ideal.

Comment: Have you tried to use BQ script and declare the string variable `description`, which first is populated by a query result, and then is used in your query?

Comment: @HuiZheng yes, and that should work fine. However if I want to set a different description for 10 different columns, that would be 10 different declare and set statements. I'm hoping to avoid that if possible and set the description directly without a variable needed.

Comment: not clear what exactly your goal and why scripting will not work for you. can you share your desire using if not 10 but let's say 3 columns so we see what you are looking for